# Postgres, Rails 4, Heroku - group by one column but select all columns

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, group-by

This question is possibly a duplicate but after reading through various answers to the similar questions and I have yet to create a working solution.

I have the model `Post` in rails 4. We can imagine it only having `id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, and `body` attributes.

My goal is to return `posts` grouped by the day they were created. My first attempt was:

`Post.group('date(created_at')` which translates to `SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"  GROUP BY date(created_at)`

This yields the error

`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "posts.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

My understanding is that this error is because Postgres needs you to include the columns that you `SELECT` in the group method. My confusion lies in the fact that, as I understand it, to include all the columns in the `group` clause would essentially result in them not being grouped. My hunch is that what I am missing lies in the last part of the error:

`or be used in an aggregate function`

That's where I am at, I am not sure what is meant by "an aggregate function" and ultimately, I still do not know how to `group` my `posts` by the day they were created.

If you need any more details please ask and I'll add them.

Comment: What is the intent of your grouping? Generally you use GROUP BY in SQL specifically to group values for aggregate functions, perhaps GROUP BY isn't the right tool for what you want to do.

Comment: @muistooshort I want display `posts` grouped by the day they were posted. So under the header "july 21st 2014" would be all the posts created that day, then "july 20th, 2014", etc., etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think an SQL GROUP BY is the right tool for this job, [`Enumerable#group_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) is the grouper you're looking for.

[SQL's GROUP BY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUP) is:

> [...] used to group together those rows in a table that have the same values in all the columns listed. The order in which the columns are listed does not matter. The effect is to combine each set of rows having common values into one group row that represents all rows in the group. This is done to eliminate redundancy in the output and/or compute aggregates that apply to these groups.

so you use GROUP BY to collect rows that have something in common so that you can ignore their differences or apply aggregates to each group (e.g. find per-group extrema, count the size of each group, per-group averages, ...). When you GROUP BY, the original rows more or less their independent identities.

If you're paginating results then sort by `date(created_at)` to get sensible pages and use `Enumerable#group_by` in Ruby-land to chunk things for presentation:

```
posts   = Post.where(...).order('date(created_at)')...
by_date = posts.group_by { |p| p.created_at.to_date }
```

That leaves you with a nice simple Hash in `by_date` which maps the dates to arrays of `Post`s. Displaying the `by_date` stuff should be fairly straight forward.

If you're not paginating, then you don't need to order things at all inside the database, just pull 'em all out (`posts = Post.where(...)...`) and proceed to `group_by` as above.

Comment: It is possible I made my question too simplistic. I can update it or maybe the best thing would be to accept this as the answer and open a new question. I would like to return only 10 posts per day. this method would grab everything for each day and then group. It is possible that there are lots of posts for each day, so I need to make this optimization.

Comment: I think I am understanding the `group by` stuff. Basically, I would use it if I was interested in some statistics on a "per day" basis? The simplest just being to count the number of posts per day?

Comment: If you only want at most 10 posts per day then you might want to look into window functions to find your chunks, something like `select * from (select *, row_number() over (partition by date(created_at) order by whatever) as rn from table) as dt where rn <= 10` in SQL. Yes, you'd GROUP BY if you wanted stats/aggregates/... computed over each group.